# Cannot get or set the window size of some apps using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

For some apps, such as Notes, or VLC, the following can be used:

```
tell application "Notes" to get the bounds of the window 1
```

if I put the above line into a file and use `sudo osascript thatfilename` to invoke it, it works.

But for some apps such as the Angry Birds Space, the following will not work?

```
tell application "Angry Birds Space" to get the bounds of the window 1
```

giving an error:

```
execution error: Angry Birds Space got an error: Can’t get bounds of 
  window 1. (-1728)
```

Is there something special of that app that prevents it?  (because it is a game or does it not have window 1?)

I am looking into getting and setting the `bounds` or just the `width` of some window (just the width as some window seem to have to have a specific aspect ratio, so I think setting it to a specific width and height may not work if the aspect ratio isn't correct).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the application is not scriptable, you won't be able to get this kind of information from it.  If you have the **System Preferences > Accessibility** preference for "Enable access for assistive devices" set, you may be able to use the **System Events** processes suite to get/set the window size, for example:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Angry Birds Space"
    get size of window 1
end tell
```

Note: Enabling accessibility varies gravely between macOS versions. [How to Enable Accessibility on Mac OS X](https://mizage.com/help/accessibility.html)
 is a good guide. As of 10.14, you have to go to Security & Privacy > Accessibility option > Privacy tab and add the application in the "Allow the apps below to control your computer".

Comment: it works, but can it possibly do `set bounds of window 1 to {100, 100, 1200, 800}`? right now it gives an error... interesting also that Notes can be resized in the original way, but using "System Events" it'd also give an error... And I just found out that I can set size and position to `{x, y}` separately

Comment: An application may provide a bounds property (if it is scriptable), but it doesn't have to - it provides whatever property names and values the developer wants.  In the case of **System Events**, the window boundaries can be determined by the **position** and **size** properties, where **position** is a 2 item list of the {left, top}, and **size** is a 2 item list of the {width, height}.

Comment: @user866649 thanks for the great answer, but as a heads up for people coming here from various search engines, `Enable access for assistive devices` has been moved to `Security and Privacy` on macOS 10.12

Answer (score 13):

Is Angry Birds Space scriptable? If not, telling it do anything should not work. A similar example would be:

```
tell application "Preview" to get the bounds of the window 1
```

As Red Menace points out, you can use the application process like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Preview"
    tell window 1
        set {size, position} to {{1280, 800}, {50, 50}}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: an app has to be scriptable?  in that case what method may be used to resize it to 1200 x 800 and at position (50, 50)?